# How can I sum values with same column and row

Tags: python, pandas

I have four matrices. I structured it with Panda with column and row names. 
I want to sum four matrices with the same row and column name to get 8x8 matrix.
To make it clear;

Matrix 1:
row 1 column 1 -> 1

Matrix 3:
row 1 column 1 -> 0.64

I want to sum only 1 and 0.64.
So in my new 8x8 matris row 1 column 1 -> 1.64

Sorry for my weak English. I hope you understand.

I tried if condition but I couldn't make up a good if condition.

```
matris = pd.DataFrame(matris, columns=column_names, index=row_names)
```

[Click to access my matric structure](https://i.hizliresim.com/pbJoyL.png)

Comment: I'm not an expert on dataframes specifically, but have you tried `final_matrix = matrix1 + matrix2 + matrix3 + ...`? I know in actual math what you described is exactly how matrices are added together

Comment: Show some code / example data please.

Comment: Show your input data, and expected output

Comment: Sorry for late reply, after checking here it is already solved. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `add` method (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas.DataFrame.add)) because it allows "addition of dataframe and other, element-wise".

Thus, if your four DataFrameare named df1, df2, df3 and df4, you can add them up in this way:

```
df1.add(df2.add(df3.add(df4)))
```

if all the dataframes have the same indexes and columns, that will work perfectly for you. Otherwise, you could just make a sum of the values of each DataFrame:

```
df1.values + df2.values + df3.values + df4.values
```

Such solution will work nicely if all the DataFrames have the same shape, regardless if they different column names and/or index labels.